# How to implement plugin system

Tags: symfony, plugins, twig, bundle

Anyone could tell me is it possible to create in Symfony2 next:

- One main Bundle: functionality, layout, templates;
- Many other Bundles: additional functionality, extending templates from main Bundle;

Tried to draw an example of idea https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv15wcxhdvamu9u/sym.png

More about idea: for example we have one layout.html.twig where we have 3 blocks. in each block we have some content from main Bundle and some special tag/mark/(controller call) - it will trigger all other bundles, and if any bundle has some content for that tag/mark/(controller call) it will return the result (e.g. block with buttons "toolbar", we have few buttons from main Bundle, and few buttons from other Bundles).

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, is possible, but needs much work.

Comment: as i see implementation will be something like that: in config.yml add main bundle config with properties where you can add bundles names, for example: main_bundle: toolbar: [Bundle1, Bundle2]. in main layout.html.twig in block for toolbar do a call to some special controller in main bundle, this controller will call some predefined class::function by each bundle in list of bundles for toolbar. any other ideas?

Comment: Firstly you have to famirialize with http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: @Pazi - to abstract answer, could you write some ideas, i don't need code, just an idea.

Comment: @NHG - why did you advise that?

Comment: You may check how Magento or Prestashop shopping systems used Symfony and integrated a plugin and templating system.